# I forgot the password for my me.com account. how can I get it?

Tags: macos

I am trying to get save on my iCloud but I can't remember the password of my me.com account.  how do I reset the password?  I tried everything I thought it might be.  I tried to change it but can't remember my hint.  It doesn't do any good to have an email sent to me when I can't remember the password for the account.  What do I do?

Comment: Have you contacted Apple Support?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://iforgot.apple.com and follow the instructions there.